# Time formatting strings in Python

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert these strings of numbers into a "hh:mm:ss" format. The strings are all different lengths, here are a few:

```
(212812, 218654, 232527, 235959, 0, 181240, 25959, 153834)
```

So I want to turn the above numbers into this:

```
(21:28:12, 21:86:54, 23:25:27, 23:59:59, 00:00:00, 18:12:40, 2:59:59, 15:38:34)
```

I'm mostly having trouble with getting them all the same length, like converting 0 to 00:00:00.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're making up (or someone you know is making up) your own time serialization format, perhaps you could explain it to us if we're meant to help you deserialize it? What time is `1234`?

Comment: Why does `0` become `00:00:00`, but `25959` only becomes `2:59:59` and not `02:59:59`?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in comments, it's unclear what the right answer is for some inputs (e.g. 1234, which my code would say is 00:12:34). I also decided that 02:59:59 is a better answer than 2:59:59, given the desire to get 00:00:00.

So here's my code, which deals with all of the above inputs correctly, modulo the 2:59:59 variation I chose:

```
import re

def convert(numeric_time):
    return ':'.join(re.findall('..', str(numeric_time).zfill(6)))

times = (212812, 218654, 232527, 235959, 0, 181240, 25959, 153834)
correct_answers = ['21:28:12', '21:86:54', '23:25:27', '23:59:59', '00:00:00', '18:12:40', '02:59:59', '15:38:34']

answers = map(convert, times)
for answer, correct_answer in zip(answers, correct_answers):
    assert answer == correct_answer, '{} != {}'.format(answer, correct_answer)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since some people object to the regular expression, here's a similar version that doesn't rely on it:

```
def convert(numeric_time):
    padded_time = str(numeric_time).zfill(6)
    return ':'.join(padded_time[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(padded_time), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well since we're making up answers here's a "solution" that doesn't use regexes:

```
In [3]: def weird_time_format(fmt):
   ...:     fmt = str(fmt)
   ...:     hours = fmt[:2].ljust(2, '0')
   ...:     mins = fmt[2:4].ljust(2, '0')
   ...:     secs = fmt[4:6].ljust(2, '0')
   ...:     return ':'.join((hours, mins, secs))
   ...:

In [4]: weird_time_format(212812)
Out[4]: '21:28:12'
```

This takes advantage of the fact that string slices are nice about out-of-bound indexes and return an empty string rather than throwing an error:

```
In [1]: ''[1:2]
Out[1]: ''

In [2]: ''[1:2].ljust(2, '0')
Out[2]: '00'
```

Here's the results for your example input:

```
In [5]: example_input = (212812, 218654, 232527, 235959, 0, 181240, 25959, 153834)

In [6]: tuple(map(weird_time_format, example_input))
Out[6]:
('21:28:12',
 '21:86:54',
 '23:25:27',
 '23:59:59',
 '00:00:00',
 '18:12:40',
 '25:95:90',
 '15:38:34')
```

And since I brought it up, what it does to `1234`:

```
In [7]: weird_time_format(1234)
Out[7]: '12:34:00'
```

---

OK, I felt (a little) bad for being facetious. If you're genuinely interested in this approach, this will work better and is more in line with the other answer's output:

```
In [3]: def weird_time_format(fmt):
   ...:     fmt = str(fmt).rjust(6, '0')
   ...:     return ':'.join((fmt[:2], fmt[2:4], fmt[4:6]))
```

Comment: What time is it? "95 minutes past 25, by my watch."

Comment: Why would you pad zeros to the right rather than the left?

Comment: Because then you get fun times like `25:95:90` to go along with `21:86:54` from the example.

Comment: Oh, I see. Taking the more cynical approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt.

The basic concept is adding `0` if input string length less than `6`.

```
a = (212812, 218654, 232527, 235959, 0, 181240, 25959, 153834)
input_list = map(str,a)
for input in input_list:
    if len(input) != 6:
        input = ''.join(['0' for i in range((6 - len(input)))]+list(input))
    print ':'.join([input[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0,len(input),len(input)/3)])
```

**Result**

```
21:28:12
21:86:54
23:25:27
23:59:59
00:00:00
18:12:40
02:59:59
15:38:34
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
data = (212812, 218654, 232527, 235959, 0, 181240, 25959, 153834)
time = map(str, data) #int to string


def conv(time_array):
    for t in time_array:
        if(len(t) != 6):
            t = str(t.zfill(6)) #filling 0's if less than 6
        print ':'.join(t[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(t), 2)) #adding ':' 

conv(time)
```

**OUTPUT**
Using some test data

```
test = (1234, 23, 133, 6)
00:12:34
00:00:23
00:01:33
00:00:06
```